# How to force a Java application to use a version different from the Tomcat's current version?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Java application that was written in 1.8. I need to deploy it to a remote Tomcat instance, that runs on 1.7.

Is it possible to force a Java application to use specific version, i.e. a version different from Tomcat's current? Preferably via the source code or Maven's `pom.xml`.

The system is Debian 7.6. Java 8 could be successfully installed concurrently to other versions.

Comment: If that app isn't using java 8 features you may be able to recompile it with 7 as target. The target is specified in the pom. But once it's compiled for 8 it has to run on a v8 JVM or later.

Comment: Well it actually has some Java 8 features. Not a lot of but sufficiently many enough to consider where to put effort: replacing them with 7-compatible code or to find a way to deploy it to Tomcat that uses 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Tomcat and you application run inside the same JVM, so tomcat needs to run in a 1.8 JVM to support your application.

You probably have to configure your system default java to be 1.8 and make sure its installed.

Installing oracles JVM on debian: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

Comment: Don't know how it works on Debian, but on Windows, the Tomcat service does not use the system default Java. It uses the java that was given (explicit or by default) when the service was created.

Comment: OK, considering other alternatives, I think this is the best one. As stated in the question Java 8 could be already successfully installed (using the above tutorial ;). This is not my own server, but if there is no alternative then we'll need to go with 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows, but I am not sure on Debian.

I use this on my pom.xml to build my web applications to a specific java version (this snippet is configured at Java 1.7)

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Hope it helps

EDIT: As mentioned above, make sure your app doesnt use any Java 8 features